# VS code.Выбивает эту ошибку во всех файлах, до этого не мог найти GCC

Tags: c, файлы, visual-studio-code, gcc, type-error

VS code.Выбивает эту ошибку во всех файлах, до этого не мог найти GCC[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120) Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])